# Unable to set height of custom web component

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component

In the following css I am trying to make the custom component height be 50px. But, takes the height of the child element instead. How can I give the custom component the height of 50px? The custom component is wcia-slider and I am setting the height with css to 50px. Then the child element has height of 100%. The wcia-slider height is being set to the childs height of 100%. I am trying to set the wcia-slider to be 50px via css settings. thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>                              1
            wcia-slider {
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                border-radius: 3px;
                height: 50px;
                width: 500px;
                background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc 25%,
                  transparent 25%),linear-gradient(-45deg, #ccc 25%,
                  transparent 25%),linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%,
                  #ccc 75%),linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #ccc 75%);
                background-size: 16px 16px;
                background-position: 0 0, 0 8px, 8px -8px, -8px 0px;
            }
    
            .bg-overlay {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                border-radius: 3px;
                background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000 0%, #ff000000 100%);
            }
    
            .thumb {
                margin-top: -1px;
                left: 250px;
                width: 5px;
                height: calc(100% - 5px);
                position: absolute;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 3px;
                border-color: white;
                border-radius: 3px;
                pointer-events: none;
                box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
                            0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    
            }
    
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <wcia-slider backgroundcolor="#0000ff" value="180"></wcia-slider>
    </body>
    <script>
        class Slider extends HTMLElement {
            connectedCallback() {

                this.innerHTML = '<div class="bg-overlay"></div><div class="thumb"></div>'

            }
        }
        if (!customElements.get('wcia-slider')) {
            customElements.define('wcia-slider', Slider);
        }

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: When I copied your code into an editor there was that number (1) in your style declarations. As soon as I removed it the height was 50px.

Comment: Install Prettier (or something similar) in your IDE to automatically verify your HTML/CSS/JS

Comment: Yes. Oh man, what a goof on my part. Thank you! Should I delete this post or leave it?